# Python 3 : How to create commands in loop for buttons grid?

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop, button, tkinter

I just began learning Python to help me create a little UI to manage my windows clients on my renderfarm. Here is an example of my problem :

```
import tkinter as tk

#my variable : number of clients specified by the user
NUMCLIENTS = 10

class APP(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)

        for i in range (0,NUMCLIENTS):
            i = i+1

            #name buttons, commands and texts
            button = ("b",i,"_01")
            CMD = ("command"+str(i))
            RN = ("RN0"+str(i))

            #create buttons on grid with text
            self.button = tk.Button(self, text= RN, command = self.CMD)
            self.button.grid(row=i, column=0, sticky="s, n, e, w")

    #the command I want to duplicate for each button
    def CMD (self):
        #print the button name
        print (RN)         

app = APP()
app.mainloop()
```

I need to create as many rows as I have clients (specified in the variable "NUMCLIENTS") and associate a specific command for each one of them, like :

```
button1 pressed => print text "RN01"
button2 pressed => print text "RN02"
```

... etc.

I don't how to loop my command like I looped the button and associate the both. I saw somewhere there might be a "late binding" problem with looping functions. I tried using lists but never succeed.

I hope you can help me with that.

Thanks for your help and your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Similar questions have been answered before.  The issue with creating variant command in a loop *is* a binding issue.  Briefly, the changes your need are

```
def cmd(self, name): print(name)
...
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text= RN,
                            command=lambda name=text: self.cmd(name))
```

EDIT: add working example with correction to `name=` part.

```
import tkinter as tk
root = tk.Tk()
def cmd(name):
    print('Button ', name)
for i in range(3):
    txt = 'B'+ str(i)
    tk.Button(text=txt, command=lambda name=txt:cmd(name)).pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Lambda seems to be the operator I need. But in this case "text" can't be used in "lambda name=text: self.cmd(name)" because is not defined. So I changed it with "RN" but it doesn't work either : all buttons print "RN010" (my "NUMCLIENTS").

Comment: If you changed to `lambda name=RN: self.cmd(name)` and `RN` is a string, as it seem to be (`RN = "RN0"+str(i)`, no parens needed), then a different string value should be captured in each loop. I edited answer with complete example that works.

Answer (score 1):

like that it works better :

```
def cmd(self, name): print(name)
...
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text= RN,
                            command=lambda name=RN: self.cmd(name)
```

And if I want more variables :

```
def cmd(self, var1, var2):
    print(var1)
    print(var2)
...
    self.button = tk.Button(self, text= RN,
                            command=lambda var1=button, var2=RN : self.cmd(var1, var2))
```

Thanks again for your help.